# Grails Unit Testing Issues

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-controller

I am having issues while testing my grails controllers, as it depends on one service which seems not to be injected. I tried several ways (for ex. Extending classess like grailsunitestcase, specification) but I keep getting errors. The thing is that that service variable is null and I cant test my controller index method (which calls a render view) due to the exception...
I really need to know how to do this but I don't have a clue where to start...

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are just that. There is no grails 'environment' surrounding your controller.  If the controller makes use of a service which is normally injected, you have to mock that service yourself.

```
@TestFor(SomeController)
@Mock([SomeService])
class SomeControllerSpec extends Specification
    def "test some method"() {
        given:
            def mockService = mockFor(SomeService)
            mockService.demand.someServiceMethod() { ->
                return something
            }

            controller.someService = mockService.createMock()
        when:
            controller.someControllerMethod()
        then:
           // whatever checks are appropriate
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi railsdog... Thankx for your answer !. I dont knw what happened but when I hand in the project the services of the tested controllers where injected and all was working ok... But suddenly all the tested methods work ok but minus one... Icant see something specific happening but well.. I understand the is no app server running thus no container injecting the dependencies... I am frustrated as this could mean me entering a company... Thankx again dude for your time